# C# NUnit No suitable constructor found even when using TestFixture

Tags: c#, nunit

I'm using NUnit in C# to do some unit tests. I have this class inheritance structure:

```
[TestFixture(null)]
public abstract class BaseTests
{
    protected BaseTests(StatusesEnum? status)
    {
    }

    [Test]
    public abstract void TestMethod_1();
}



[TestFixture(null)]
public class SalesTests : BaseTests
{
    protected SalesTests(StatusesEnum? status) : base(status)
    {
    }

    //When I run this test from this class it throws the "No suitable constructor was found"
    [Test]
    public override void TestMethod_1()
    {
    }
}



//When I run the test from this class it works perfectly since it passes value to the constructor
public class CustomerTests : SalesTests
{
    public CustomerTests() : base (StatusesEnum.New) { }
}
```

When I'm running the `CustomerTests` they run perfectly and they call the `TestMEthos_1` from the `SalesTests` as expected.

But when I'm running only the `SalesTests` class I keep getting the exception of `No suitable constructor found`. The expected result should be that the `status` parameter will be null and the tests should pass since I'm checking that parameter in the tests method.

I found many answers saying to simply add `[TestFixture]` attribute but that didn't help as well.
So any idea on how to fix that would be great.

Comment: What is the exact full error? Also - Resharper or built-in VS test runner?

Comment: The exact error is "No suitable constructor was found" ans I'm using the built-in VS tests

Comment: Just that? Nothing else? Can you please add a screenshot if possible please?

Comment: I also tried passing StatusEnum.New and it didn't work as well

Comment: Can you add in a default constructor for the class? That would solve the issue - what provlem are you trying to solve? What's the point of having something hardcoded passed to the test?

Comment: I did the default ctor as well. I have no idea what else to try

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by simply changing both base classes (`BaseTests` & `SalesTests`) to be `abstract` since `abstract class` does not run tests on its own, only the inheriting classes run their tests.

```
public abstract class BaseTests
{
    protected BaseTests(StatusesEnum? status)
    {
    }

    [Test]
    public abstract void TestMethod_1();
}

public abstract class SalesTests : BaseTests
{
    protected SalesTests(StatusesEnum? status) : base(status)
    {
    }

    [Test]
    public override void TestMethod_1()
    {
    }
}

public class CustomerTests : SalesTests
{
    public CustomerTests() : base (StatusesEnum.New) { }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that `NUnit` requires constructor to be public. Next setup worked for me (changed `SalesTests` ctor accessibility modifier and added `TestFixtureAttribute` to `CustomerTests`):

```
[TestFixture(null)]
public class SalesTests : BaseHfsTests
{
    public SalesTests(StatusesEnum? status) : base(status)
    {
    }

    [Test]
    public override void TestMethod_1()
    {
    }
}

[TestFixture]
public class CustomerTests : SalesTests
{
    public CustomerTests() : base(StatusesEnum.New)
    {
        
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm almost certain that I tried public as well

Comment: @LiranFriedman I got the same error with your code, changing constructor access modifiers to `public` fixed it for me. Though I have not found any confirmation in the docs.

Comment: And did you leave the [TestFixture(null)]? Also, did you try to run the Sales Tests and not only the CustomerTests?

Comment: @LiranFriedman I've copied your code completely (only renamed `SalesBasedOnWeekDayTests` -> `SalesTests`). And run both tests.

Comment: My apologies, the SalesTests was a rename I did to shorten the class for this post. In my code there was no typo

Comment: @LiranFriedman NP. What runtime/version of NUnit are you using?

Comment: I believe that the latest